# React and Django: Edit function of CRUD app not working

Tags: reactjs, django, redux

I'm working on a CRUD app (blog app basically), i sucessfully created the create, read and delete functionality, only update/edit is not working. Im a beginner with redux i really need your help guys to make my app work.

I deployed the code on bitbucket

frontend --> https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/frontend-part-of-blog-app/src/master/src/

backend --> https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/backend-part-of-block-app/src/master/

and the backend looks like this (pic below)

[image]

Comment: Here you have a good example: [CRUD in Django Rest Framework and React](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/crud-django-rest-framework-react/)

Comment: @pplonski thanks a lot for the example, that really helped ️

Comment: @pplonski i applied changes according to the tutorial you suggested, the edit form is working fine but each time when i try to submit the blog the id is not getting detected (getting 404 error and id is undefined), but its getting detected in console.

Comment: Please do a new stack overflow ticket with code example or link to repo - I will try to help! Are available to list all posts?

Comment: @pplonski  i managed to fix the error, but new values are not updating (old values are not changing even after edits). i uploaded my backend as well here https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/backend-part-of-block-app/src/master/

Comment: The backend code looks good. How do you perform update?

Comment: please see the frontend repo for that.

Comment: it is not available in the repo ;)

Comment: @pplonski here's the link for update function https://bitbucket.org/Yash-Marmat/frontend-part-of-blog-app/src/master/src/reducers/blogs.js (whole frontend repo link in question also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When edit a post you are using:

```
    const data = {
      newTitle,
      newDescription
    };
```

In your model there is:

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
```

When you send data for update the DRF can not match `newTitle` with `title`, the same with `description`.

Your data send for update should be:

```
    const data = {
      title: newTitle,
      description: newDescription
    };
```